How to efficiently extract individual files from 7z archives efficiently in Python?
I have downloaded 424 files from Nexusmods using a Python script I wrote. They have a total size of 21.5GiB and they are all either .zip, .rar or .7z files (some .zip files are renamed to .dazip files).
I am trying to write a program to unpack these files automatically. I know I can use 7z to extract these files in batch, keeping all directory structures or not keep directory structures, in the following syntax:
7z x "C:\blah\blah blah blah.7z" -o"D:\foo bar\"
7z e "C:\blah\blah blah blah.7z" -o"D:\foo bar\"
But I won't use it, because first, I find it extremely hard to pass the command line arguments to this program, because most of these files have spaces in their names. And I want to extract the files in the archives to a folder with the same fullpath as the archive just without the extension.
For whatever reason, the following command doesn't work:
subprocess.run(["7z", "x", f'"{file}"', f'-o"{file.rsplit(".", 1)[0]}"'])

It complains about file not found or invalid path. Of course I tried to pass the arguments without hard coded quotes, that doesn't work either.
And 7z is blocking synchronous program, I want asynchronousity.
But then, most of these archives have bad directory structures, redundant folders, way too many levels of nested folders, and many useless files that I would rather not extract, these useless files are readmes, images and the like.
I want to extract the files without the directory structures, and discard all the junk files. But I can't just extract all of these archives in this way, because some archives contain files with the same name, but in different paths, some have the same CRC32, others don't. When there are files with the same name but with different CRC32 then the whole archive must be extracted keeping all those redundant nested folders.
I have seen many questions like this: How to read contents of 7z file using python
None of these answers provide what I am looking for.
pyunpack and patool are just wrappers for command line programs, they don't expose any information for experts at all, they are for technically illiterate people, pyunpack.Archive provides these following three functions: extractall, extractall_patool and extractall_zipfile. None of them are what I want.
I have already solved this problem for .rar and .zip. I use rarfile and zipfile libraries which provide exactly what I am looking for for the respective file formats, and they have the same API, but neither of them support .7z.
Below is the code I use to extract .zip files, it works perfectly, and the code to extract .rar is exactly the same, but the class used was RarFile instead of ZipFile and the attribute was named accordingly. Many functions are omitted, but what is given should give you an idea about what exactly I want.
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import os
import stat
import subprocess
from aiopath import AsyncPath
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from datetime import datetime
from py7zr import SevenZipFile
from rarfile import RarFile
from zipfile import ZipFile


INFO_POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=64)
EXTRACT_POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16)

class AsyncZip:
    def __init__(self, archive):
        self.archive = archive.replace("\\", "/").lower()
        self.filename = self.archive.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
        self.zipfile = ZipFile(archive)
        self.cases = {}
        INFO_POOL.submit(self.get_metadata)
        self.extracted = set()
    
    def get_metadata(self):
        self.crcs = {}
        self.paths = {}
        self.names = {}
        for item in self.zipfile.infolist():
            if not item.is_dir():
                path = item.filename.lower()
                self.cases[path] = item.filename
                timestamp = datetime(*item.date_time)
                crc = item.CRC
                self.crcs.setdefault(crc, []).append(path)
                root, leaf = '', path
                if "/" in path:
                    root, leaf = path.rsplit("/", 1)
                
                self.paths[path] = (leaf, root, item.file_size, timestamp, crc)
                self.names.setdefault(leaf, []).append(path)

    async def extract(self, path, dest):
        path = path.lower()
        if path in self.extracted:
            return

        async with aiofiles.open(dest, mode="wb") as fw:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            with self.zipfile.open(self.cases[path]) as fr:
                await fw.write(await loop.run_in_executor(EXTRACT_POOL, fr.read))
        
        os.utime(dest, (datetime.now().timestamp(), self.paths[path][3].timestamp()))
        self.extracted.add(path)
    
    async def extract_files_flat(self, files, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        await AsyncPath(dest_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                self.extract(self.names[file.lower()][0], f"{dest_folder}/{file}") 
                for file in files
            )
        )
    
    async def extract_all_files_flat(self, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        await AsyncPath(dest_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                self.extract(paths[0], f"{dest_folder}/{name}")
                for name, paths in self.names.items()
            )
        )
    
    async def extract_files_keep_directory(self, files, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        args = []
        folders = set()
        for file in files:
            file = file.lower()
            dest = dest_folder + "/" + self.paths[file][1]
            folders.add(dest)
            args.append((file, dest + "/" + file.rsplit('/')[-1]))
        
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                AsyncPath(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
                for folder in folders
            )
        )
        
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                self.extract(file, dest) 
                for file, dest in args
            )
        )
    
    async def extract_all_files_keep_directory(self, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        args = []
        folders = set()
        for path, datum in self.paths.items():
            dest = dest_folder + "/" + datum[1]
            folders.add(dest)
            args.append((path, dest + "/" + datum[0]))
                
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                AsyncPath(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
                for folder in folders
            )
        )
        
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                self.extract(file, dest) 
                for file, dest in args
            )
        )

I got almost what I want with py7zr:
class Async7zip:
    def __init__(self, archive):
        self.archive = archive.replace("\\", "/").lower()
        self.filename = self.archive.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
        self.sevenzip = SevenZipFile(archive)
        self.cases = {}
        INFO_POOL.submit(self.get_metadata)
        self.extracted = set()
    
    def get_metadata(self):
        self.crcs = {}
        self.paths = {}
        self.names = {}
        for item in self.sevenzip.list():
            if not item.is_directory:
                path = item.filename.lower()
                self.cases[path] = item.filename
                timestamp = item.creationtime
                crc = item.crc32
                self.crcs.setdefault(item.crc32, []).append(path)
                root, leaf = '', path
                if "/" in path:
                    root, leaf = path.rsplit("/", 1)
                
                self.paths[path] = (leaf, root, item.uncompressed, timestamp, crc)
                self.names.setdefault(leaf, []).append(path)
    
    async def extract(self, path, dest):
        path = path.lower()
        if path in self.extracted:
            return
        
        self.sevenzip.reset()
        async with aiofiles.open(dest, mode="wb") as fw:
            length = self.paths[path][2]
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            ocase = self.cases[path]
            fr = self.sevenzip.read(ocase)[ocase]
            await fw.write(await loop.run_in_executor(EXTRACT_POOL, fr.read))
            
        os.utime(dest, (datetime.now().timestamp(), self.paths[path][3].timestamp()))
        self.extracted.add(path)


    async def extract_files_flat(self, files, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        await AsyncPath(dest_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for file in files:
            await self.extract(self.names[file.lower()][0], f"{dest_folder}/{file}")
    
    async def extract_all_files_flat(self, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        await AsyncPath(dest_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        for name, paths in self.names.items():
            await self.extract(paths[0], f"{dest_folder}/{name}")

    
    async def extract_files_keep_directory(self, files, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        args = []
        folders = set()
        for file in files:
            file = file.lower()
            dest = dest_folder + "/" + self.paths[file][1]
            folders.add(dest)
            args.append((file, dest + "/" + file.rsplit('/')[-1]))
        
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                AsyncPath(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
                for folder in folders
            )
        )
        
        for file, dest in args:
            await self.extract(file, dest)
    
    async def extract_all_files_keep_directory(self, dest_folder):
        dest_folder = dest_folder.replace("\\", "/").rstrip("/")
        args = []
        folders = set()
        for path, datum in self.paths.items():
            dest = dest_folder + "/" + datum[1]
            folders.add(dest)
            args.append((path, dest + "/" + datum[0]))
                
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                AsyncPath(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
                for folder in folders
            )
        )
        
        for file, dest in args:
            await self.extract(file, dest)

It does work, it indeed works, save for a huge problem: it is extremely inefficient. For whatever reason using py7zr.SevenZipFile to .read or .extract single files in large archives with hundreds or thousands of files takes extremely long time, I guess it scans the whole archive for every single file I want to extract. I cannot use it, it is way too inefficient.
I have seen many posts on this site asking how to extract 7z files, and the popular answers are patool, pyunpack and py7zr. But as I have demonstrated they don't suit my use case at all.
I have also checked lzma.LZMAFile and it behaves exactly like a Python file object, it doesn't even list the files contained in the archive...
So what are my options for my desired use case?

So I guess my original assumptions are wrong. py7zr indeed performs much worse than 7z, if I try to .extractall.
However extracting a single file is somehow much more inefficient than just extracting the whole archive.
I have also used a bunch other libraries, such as py7zlib from pylzma, they all have the same issue, extracting a single file is much less efficient than extracting the whole archive.
Interestingly enough, PeaZip has the same issue and of course I know it is just a GUI wrapper for 7-Zip, extracting a single file from a large archive takes way longer than it should, and from my testing extracting multiple files doesn't take much longer time than extracting a single file, maybe even faster.
And extracting all files seems to be the most efficient option, I don't know why, but it seems evident 7-Zip is well parallelized.
And I have learned the correct syntax to extract files selectively by looking at the console tab in the extraction window of PeaZip:
"C:\Program Files\PeaZip\res\7z\7z.exe" x -aoa "-oD:\downloads\mods\dragonage\YAHD - Yet Another HD Mod (and Fixes)\YAHD - AIO (Origins)-6233-3-0-1712997503\" -bb0 -bse0 -bsp2 -pdefault -sccUTF-8 "D:\downloads\mods\dragonage\YAHD - Yet Another HD Mod (and Fixes)\YAHD - AIO (Origins)-6233-3-0-1712997503.7z" "-i!z_YAHD\z_YAHD_Creatures_Bodies\c_ashwrath_0n.dds" "-i!z_YAHD\z_YAHD_Creatures_Bodies\c_ashwrath_0s.dds" "-i!z_YAHD\z_YAHD_Creatures_Bodies\c_berkbeara_0d.dds" "-i!z_YAHD\z_YAHD_Creatures_Bodies\c_berkbeara_0n.dds" "-i!z_YAHD\z_YAHD_Creatures_Bodies\c_berkbeara_0s.dds" "-i!z_YAHD\z_YAHD_Creatures_Bodies\c_blacbeara_0d.dds" "-i!z_YAHD\z_YAHD_Creatures_Bodies\c_blacbeara_0n.dds"

So I guess I will just use 7z to extract the files.

Please focus your question on one specific aspect and limit the code, etc to just that. [ask] and [mre]

That's a lot of code to go through. It may just be that you have added shell quotes to the run command parameters. Since you are not going through the shell (or at least python will escape them for you on windows), leave them out. subprocess.run(["7z", "x", file, f'-o{file.rsplit(".", 1)[0]}'])

You do not want to extract 400+ files concurrently. The drive and OS will perform much more effectively if you process them sequentially. The extraction utilities already parallelise resource utilisation for you.

How about doing a 3-step process? First, Discard files with the same CRC32.   Then, extract all the .7z files keeping the folder structure intact. Finally, flatten out all the files with your provided logic.

As tdelaney says -- the big problem here is that you're adding extra quotes. When a command goes through a shell, that shell removes the quotes it parsed as syntax ("syntactic quotes") and passes only the subset of quotes that were data ("literal quotes") on the program being run, after using the syntactic quoting to decide where to put boundaries between arguments. Here, where you're explicitly setting the argument boundaries in your Python code and there is no shell, every quote you add to the data within your Python strings is a literal quote.

IIRC, 7zip compression isn't happening within individual files -- instead, you have much larger chunks that can consist of many files, so if you're extracting a 5kb file you can still need to decompress the whole 128mb chunk it's inside of. (Sizes all subject to tuning; folks can make archives quicker to decompress at the cost of being somewhat larger, but that's a decision that was locked in when the files were initially compressed). So it's very, very normal for decompressing lots of small files separately to be far more expensive than decompressing them all in a single pass.
